# SharePoint 2010 - Solution struck on Retracting

Tags: solution-package, retraction

I have solution installed in my solution store. I am trying to retract the solution but is stuck on "Retracting".

Solution Tried  :
1 . Restart Timer Job services

But when i am trying to add solution and retract solution from Visual Studio i am able to do it successfully.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

If your in 2010, you may as well start getting used to Powershell.  Open up the SharePoint Management Console and run:

**Uninstall-SPSolution YourSolutionName.wsp –AllWebApplications**

**Remove-SPSolution YourSolutionName.wsp**

Comment: 15 : Powershell command Uninstall and remove does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the "Sharepoint 2010 Administration" service is running.

Answer (score 3):

Just run below steps:

- Run `stsadm -o enumdeployments` command in SharePoint Management
  Shell.
  Look for the **JobId** string corresponding to your solution. Copy that string.
- Run `stsadm -o canceldeployment -id "you job id string here"`

  Your solution wsp will be in **Not Deployed** state. Now you can easily remove that solution using PowerShell `Remove-SPSolution YourSolutionName.wsp` or from Central Administration.
- Check for **SharePoint Administration Services** in Windows Services. If it is stopped then start it.

You will get more information from [here](http://itjackofalltrades.blogspot.in/2012/05/solution-stuck-at-deploying-or.html).

Comment: stsadm -o canceldeployment -id "you job id string here" did the job, thank you

Comment: stsadm -o canceldeployment -id "you job id string here" also worked for me on SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use STSADM commands to remove a stubborn solution. I have been in this situation several times in SP2007. [This blog post](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2007/07/18/removing-malfunctioning-windows-sharepoint-services-solutions.aspx) covers all the steps.

Caveat: I don't THINK that SP2010 has changed the STSADM commands that much, so it should still work in SP2010. Let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Run SharePoint 2010 Management Shell as administrator and then run:

`stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs`

It will manually trigger the administration jobs.

Reference: http://blog.degree.no/2012/08/sharepoint-2010-solution-stuck-retracting-deploying/

Answer (score 0):

do not run STSADM in Powershell and for some reason it does not return any error and message and is not working

- with Command Prompt change dir to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\STSADM.EXE"
- (optional) run below command and see the current probably stuck jobs

  stsadm -o enumdeployments
- stop **SharePoint 2010 administration ** service from services.msc
- now run below command and all jobs will be run manually

  stsadm  -o execadmsvcjobs

results: note the last 2 WSPs which was sucked in my case :

```
Executing job-application-server-admin-service.
Executing SecurityTokenServiceApplication.
Executing UsageManagerServiceTimerJobDefinition.
Executing job-password-management.
Executing solution-deployment-form-delegation.wsp-0.
Executing solution-deployment-form-supplierregistra.wsp-0.
Operation completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever experience that your solution never retracts (or deploys), first verify that the SharePoint Administration Service is running. If it is, restart it and see if that helps.

If your solution is still stuck, start Sharepoint 2010 Management Shell and type in the following command:

```
stsadm -o enumdeployments
```

You will see a list of in-progress or pending jobs. Cancel the pending job, either by STS / Powershell commands or through the Solution Management. No point wasting any more time – Sharepoint’s showed you another one of its ugly sides so just run this command to force your solution to be deleted:

```
Remove-SPSolution -Identity the_name_of_your_solution.wsp -force
```

There, it’s gone. But now you will most likely get an error message when re-deploying your solution:

This is because after forced solution removal, Sharepoint still believes the feature is installed. You’ll therefore have to deploy your solution from SharePoint 2010 Management Shell with the –force attribute:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity the_name_of_your_solution.wsp -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment –force
```

Note: make sure you match the scope (“AllWebApplications”) of your solution.

If your solution is STILL stuck, stop the Sharepoint Administration Service and manually trigger the administration jobs from Sharepoint 2010 Management Shell:

```
 stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
```